# ExtJS 4.1 - Changing value of JsonStore

Tags: extjs, store, javascript-framework, extjs4.1

I use ExtJS 4.1. Here's my model and store:

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['status', 'data', 'data1', 'data2']
});

var store1 = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
    model: 'MyModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'actionJsonServlet'
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

After loading the store by Ajax, I want to change value of first "status" (just for first row) of the JsonStore.
I tried lines below but it doesn't work (record is undefined at line 2):

```
var record = store1.getAt(0);
record.set("status", "Waiting");
```

I have this error:

```
Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
```

Comment: How do you load your store? Do you set the record in `on()` function?

Comment: In order to load my store, I call Java servlet by Ajax with the code above (url of proxy). My servlet returns Json data automatically loaded in my store. I don't use `on()` function. Must I use it to wait Ajax call return ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your issue is due to asynchronous nature of store load.  Depending on how your code is written you maybe attempting to do store operations too early, before the store is loaded even though you have autoLoad turned on.

The best approach is to set up a load event listener on the store and perform your operation then.
Her is an example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.Drafters', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'MyApp.model.User',
    autoLoad:true,
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'user/drafters.json',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            root:'data'
        }
    },
    listeners:{
        load:function (store, recs) {
            store.insert(0, {uid:'', name:''});  //adding empty record to enable deselection of assignment
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok for waiting Ajax return. In `load` function, instead of using an `insert`, I tried to use `store.update(0, {'status':'Waiting'});` to update status's value of the first row but it doesn't work (or the chart behind is not reloaded).

Comment: Do you get the same error? If not then your original issue and question is solved you can move on and figure out why the chart is not bound to the store correctly. I suggest creating a speciifc question for that and provide relevannt code pieces - chart setup, and store binding.

Comment: I had the same error. I finally found an other solution to solve my problem. I wanted to display other titles of slices of my pie chart and I worked on label to do what I wanted to do. Thanks for your time.